# Error: [class] is not a constructor when importing npm module in react-native application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I'm writing react-native application and using npm module `@waves/signature-adapter`. When I make `import { Seed } from '@waves/signature-generator';` compiler returns an error `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new __1.Base58('senderPublicKey')')`. At first I thought the way I imported the lib was wrong but then I tried to do the same for new react application (not react-native) and it is imported and works with no errors.
The module is written in typescript but I'm not sure it really matters cause my app uses lots of other modules written in typescript. I try to understand what's wrong cause I have same-same code in both apps, but it gives the error in react-native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the lib used native node.js modules which react-native didn't support. I had to make a patch using patch-package to solve the problem.